# Есть ли разница в кодах?

Tags: php

```
private $var;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->var = array();
    }
```

или

```
private $var = array();

    public function __construct() {

    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего нет

Answer (score 1):

Разница есть только при явном вызове конструктора. Если вы используете new, то разницы нет.
Но конструктор не для этого.

Если по-простому, то вот этого:

```
private $var;

public function __construct($some_array=array()) {
    $this->var = $some_array;
}
```

вы не добъетесь без констуктора.

(ну, разве что глобальными переменными. Но это извращение)

Answer (score -1):

Инициализация полей в конструкторе нужна в тех случаях, когда значения не просто статичные, пример:

так нельзя:

```
class Foo
{
    private $boo = array(
        ucfirst('foo'),
    );
}
```

так можно:

```
class Foo
{
    private $boo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->boo = array(
            ucfirst('foo'),
        );
    }
}
```

Инициализация полей непосредственно удобней немного короче записью и тем, что если у производного класса перегружен конструктор, нужно не забыть вызвать родительский конструктор при инициализации в конструкторе.